# How to check foursquare api oauth token expiration?

Tags: foursquare

I'm looking for documentation that explains following details:

- what is the default foursquare api oauth token expiration?
- how can I check expiration for any given token?
- how can I extend time to live for oauth tokens?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently they don't:

via [Foursquare Oauth API docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#access)

> Access tokens allow apps to make requests to Foursquare on the behalf
>   of a user. Each access token is unique to the user and consumer key.
>   Access tokens do not expire, but they may be revoked by the user. If
>   your application doesn't require connecting with Foursquare users, you
>   can skip directly to Userless Access.